# Getting API-Scope Policy XML

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, ibm-api-management

In MS Azure, I set up an API Management Service - let's call it "MyAPIMS".  Within that, I added a web app as an API - let's call that "MyWebAPI".  Within this API, I added a "set-header" policy within the Inbound processing section.  So now if I go into that API's Inbound processing policy xml, it looks like this:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="Web-App" />
    <set-header name="Referred-From" exists-action="append">
        <value>Me</value>
    </set-header>
</inbound>
```

I need to figure out how to add this policy via powershell script.  So I decided I'd try just directly using powershell commands to get this policy that I manually set up and see the result.  First, I get the context:

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "MyGroup" -ServiceName "myAPIMS"
```

If I output "$apimContext", it displays the resource group name and service name just fine.  So then I get the API:

```
$MyApi = Get-AzApiManagementApi -Context $apimContext -Name "MyWebAPI"
```

With that, if I output "$MyApi.Id", it displays the ID of MyWebAPI as:

> /subscriptions/[mysub]/resourceGroups/[mygroup]/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/MyAPIMS/apis/MyWebAPI

But then, if I try getting the API's policy, it does nothing.  Here's what I tried:

```
Get-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId $MyApi.Id -SaveAs "C:\Source\MyApiPolicy.xml"
```

No new file shows up in that location.  If I don't specify -SaveAs, it does not display any output in the terminal.

It works if I do not specify the -ApiId (as in, I can save the tenant-scope policy just fine).  So I don't understand what is it about getting the policy for the specific API that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing `$MyApi.Id` to `Get-AzApiManagementPolicy`.  You should be passing `$MyApi.ApiId` which will translate to the name of your API.

The Id property is the ARM resource id, whereas the cmdlet is expecting the API name.

Comment: Ah, OK.  "ApiId" instead of "Id" worked...thank you!!